# Fetching data from postgresql takes a ton of memory even when chunk loading

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a postgreSQL DB with around 600000 rows and 100 columns, which takes around 500 MB RAM.
I have now tried loading it via

```py
con = pyodbc.connect("DSN="+DSN)
df = pd.read_sql(query ,con)
```

ending up in 9+ GB of RAM usage and crashes due to memory error.

I have tried several work-arounds now:

"Manually" fetching the rows using `fetchmany`

```py
eng = create_engine(f'postgresql://{self.user}:{self.pwd}@{self.host}:{self.port}/{self.db}',server_side_cursors=True)
#or 
#eng = create_engine(f'postgresql://{self.user}:{self.pwd}@{self.host}:{self.port}/{self.db}',execution_options={"stream_results":True})
con = eng.connect()
ex = con.execute(query)
           
def __fetch_iter__(self,ex,chunksize):
        """
        Generator for loading in chunks
        """
        fetch = True
        while fetch:
           fetch = ex.fetchmany(chunksize)
           
           yield pd.DataFrame(fetch)

df = pd.concat(__fetch_iter__(ex,chunksize))
```

which, according to [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12265) should indeed only load the given amount of rows each time.

even with `chunksize=10` my memory goes above 6GB

Comment: How do you know it's the fetching of records from the DB that's consuming the memory, as opposed to the dataframe itself?

Comment: If it indeed is loading 10 rows with 100 columns, it should take no near 7 GB of RAM.

Comment: It's not loading 10 rows, it's loading all the rows, just 10 at a time. The pd.concat() will evaluate its argument to completion, so `df` on the final line will have all rows.

Comment: Agreed (that was badly phrased from my part) but the full dataframe does only take around 500 MB - adding some overhead here and there should by no means push it above 7 GB

Comment: How do you know that the dataframe takes only 500mb?

Comment: If I look at it in the DB and if I load it (on a machine with more RAM) and using `df.info()` it is around 500 MB

Comment: Assume we have 600 000 rows and 100 with 8 bytes pr. cell, you get 480 MB

Comment: OK, I'm convinced. I havne't used pyodbc before, so that's the first thing that stands out to me; are you able to test with psycopg2 and does that make a difference? Also, are you missing a step in your first code sample - AIUI pd.read_sql takes a SQLAlchemy, not db-api (==pyodbc), connection?

Comment: The first step is a snippet, but yes it is an sqlalchemy connection. I'm trying to convert it to a pure psycopg2 connection now, and see if that helps.